# what is the real benefit of using software testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, definition

I know that software testing (ex: unit, integration) makes sure that my functionality is working as expected, but I do not know what is its benefit since I can test the flow myself and make sure it is working as I'm expecting it to. so I need to know what is the bigger picture of software testing

Comment: Automation. Doing the flow yourself at each release will be incredibly boring and risky. When it is automatic, you cant miss a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, you can test the flow yourself. Can you really do this, once you have a big number of usecases and you want to release your software e.g. once a day (or even if it's just once a week)? Also, you would need to repeat the manual tests for each release, which in the end is wasted developer time, that can be better spent on new features.

Additionally, as soon as you work in a developer team on a software, you get the increased complexity of different people possibly testing in different ways, which might result in a lack of proper manual test coverage and in the end overlooked bugs etc.

Manual testing might be ok for a private project, or a simple tool that's only used a few times and then discarded. However, for any commercial product, that needs to make money for the company, it will not be feasible in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The objective of software testing is all about ensuring that the ultimate purpose of the software is fulfilled offering desired functionalities to the end-users. Especially, when you are releasing a marketplace application or other service-based software, testing allows you to launch a solution that can compete in the market and meet the desired objectives of the users.